# How I get rid of the error "signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)" in C++, replit?

Tags: c++, function, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am trying to print out 1-999 in English format using words.

Example:
Input: `563`
Output: `Five Hundred Sixty Three`

I made a function for 1 through 9, 10 through 19, and the numbers ending in 0 up until 99 (20, 30, 40, 50 ... 90), and I have a separate function for 100.

I have multiple functions, and then one `main()` function. In the last function, I have called all the previous functions. Also, I don't have a returning value for my functions.

When run, there is an error:

> signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)

Can someone please help me fix this? And explain how to do this?

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string digit_name(int digit) {
  // defines 1 through 9 
  if (digit == 1){
    return "One "; 
  }
  if (digit == 2){
    return "Two "; 
  }
  if (digit == 3){
    return "Three "; 
  }
  if (digit == 4){
    return "Four "; 
  }
  if (digit == 5){
    return "Five "; 
  }
  if (digit == 6){
    return "Six "; 
  }
  if (digit == 7){
    return "Seven "; 
  }
  if (digit == 8){
    return "Eight "; 
  }
  if (digit == 9){
    return "Nine"; 
  }
}

string teen_name(int number){
  // defines 10 through 19
  if (number == 10){
    return "Ten "; 
  }
  if (number == 11){
    return "Eleven "; 
  }
  if (number == 12){
    return "Twelve "; 
  }
  if (number == 13){
    return "Thirteen "; 
  }
  if (number == 14){
    return "Fourteen"; 
  }
  if (number == 15){
    return "Fifteen"; 
  }
  if (number == 16){
    return "Sixteen"; 
  }
  if (number == 17){
    return "Seventeen"; 
  }
  if (number == 18){
    return "Eighteen"; 
  }
  if (number == 19){
    return "Nineteen"; 
  }
}

string teens_name (int number){
  // defines 20 through 90 (20, 30, 40 ... 90)
  if (number == 20){
    return "Twenty "; 
  }
  if (number == 30){
    return "Thirty "; 
  }
  if (number == 40){
    return "Forty "; 
  }
  if (number == 50){
    return "Fifty "; 
  }
  if (number == 60){
    return "Sixty "; 
  }
  if (number == 70){
    return "Seventy "; 
  }
  if (number == 80){
    return "Eighty "; 
  }
  if (number == 90){
    return "Ninty "; 
  }
}

string hun_name (int number){
  // defines 100
  return "Hundred ";
}
  
string define (int number){
  // defines what it will output based on the input of the user
  // if 1 through 9, output the name (ex: One)
  if (number > 0 && number < 9){
    cout << digit_name(number);
  }
  
  // if 10 through 19, output name (ex: Seventeen)
  if (number >> 9 && number << 20){
    cout << teen_name(number);
  }

  // if number divides by 100, then it will print digit_name, then Hundred, and then the teens_name
  if (number/100){
    cout << digit_name(number) << "Hundered " << teens_name(number) << digit_name(number);
  }
  
  // if number divides by 10 evenly, then it is one of the teens (ex: Sixty)
  if (number/10 == 0){
    cout << teens_name(number);
  }

  // else, it is a number from 21-99, so it will print teens_name and then digit_name
  else{ 
    cout << teens_name(number) << digit_name(number);
  }
}

// main function - approved by Ms. B
int main() {
  int num;
  cout << "Please enter a number from 1 - 999: ";
  cin >> num;
  define (num);
}
```

Comment: 1) You forgot `#include <string>`.  2) Are you ignoring the [compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/dPd6obfx5)?  You have declared functions that return `std::string`, but you didn't keep that promise of returning `std::string` on all code paths.

Comment: `if (number >> 9 && number << 20)` doesn't do what you think it does, and because of that `teen_name` doesn't return a value. Did you mean `>` and `<` instead?

Comment: As a general rule, a segmentation fault is a sign that you access an invalid memory address. (It's not that obvious here because you have functions that don't return a string, and the code belonging to the string implementation accesses invalid "object" memory of an object that's not there.)

Comment: And one cannot emphasize @PaulMcKenzie's remark enough: Always compile with -Wall (or /W4 with MSVC) and understand and fix all warnings before you present code to anybody (us, your teacher, your employer, the world).

Comment: Also, those functions such as `digit_name` can be written in 4 lines of code if you simply used a string array and a little bit of math.

Comment: *if number divides by 100, then it will print digit_name, then Hundred, and then the teens_name* -- If your program is supposed to turn the number into words, unfortunately your code doesn't do that correctly.  It is much more than simply taking the number and feeding it to `teens_name` and `digit_name`.  Take the simple case of `300` -- I don't see where you print the word "Three" when given `300`.

Comment: *"I have multiple functions"* -- but only one of them is current when the seg fault occurs. Which one? Can you eliminate most of the other functions? Keep in mind that your question is supposed to be capable of helping others. A [mre] is better suited for this goal than a program to "print out 1-999 in English format using words".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your comment. How can I write the function digit_name in 4 lines, please explain. And yes, I did forget to add #includ <string>

Comment: @Peter - Reinstate Monica - I did not know that I could check my code and what's wrong with it using -Wall (ow /W4). This is my first year taking C++ and I am new to coding.

Comment: @JaMiT  Thank you for the comment. I will remember to keep my code as minimal as possible.

Comment: @KrishaPatel -- See the answer you accepted.  All of the strings are in a single array, and you use a small calculation to get the right string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are not validating whether the user actually enters a `number` between 1..999.  So any number outside of that range will cause your logic to fail.

Your `define()` function is declared as returning a `string` (BTW, you are missing `#include <string>`), however it does not actually `return` anything.  In fact, most of your functions have this same problem, in that they are declared as returning a `string` but not all of their code paths actually lead to a `return` statement.  That is *undefined behavior*.

Also, `define()` doesn't correctly handle the cases where `number >= 9`.  9 is skipped entirely, and you are not dividing up multi-digit numbers at all, you are just passing the whole `number` as-is to every function, which then leads your functions to paths that are missing `return` statements, causing *undefined behavior* all over the place.

Also, `define()` is using bit-shift operators `>>` and `<<` in its 2nd `if` statement, instead of using comparison operators `>` and `<`.  And, it is checking for "divides by 10 evenly" incorrectly in its 4th `if` statement, it would need to use the `%` modulus operator rather than the `/` division operator.  However, there is a better way to write your `if` statements without using any division in them.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

// defines 1 through 9 
string digit_name(int number){
  static const char* words[] = {
    "One ",
    "Two ",
    "Three ",
    "Four ",
    "Five ",
    "Six ",
    "Seven ",
    "Eight ",
    "Nine "
  };
  return words[number-1];
}

// defines 11 through 19
string teen_name(int number){
  static const char* words[] = {
    "Eleven ",
    "Twelve ",
    "Thirteen ",
    "Fourteen ",
    "Fifteen ",
    "Sixteen ",
    "Seventeen ",
    "Eighteen ",
    "Nineteen " 
  };
  return words[number-11];
}

// defines 10 through 90 (20, 30, 40 ... 90)
string tens_name (int number){
  static const char* words[] = {
    "Ten ",
    "Twenty ",
    "Thirty ",
    "Forty ",
    "Fifty ",
    "Sixty ",
    "Seventy ",
    "Eighty ",
    "Ninty "
  };
  return words[(number/10)-1];
}

// defines 100 through 900 (200, 300, 400 ... 900)
string hun_name (int number){
  return digit_name(number / 100) + "Hundred ";
}  

string define (int number){
  // defines what it will output based on the input of the user
  string result;
  
  // if number divides by 100, then it is one of the hundreds (ex: Two Hundred)
  if (number >= 100){
    result += hun_name(number);
    number %= 100;
  }
  
  // if number divides by 10...
  if (number >= 10){
    // if number is 11 through 19, output name (ex: Seventeen)
    if (number > 10 && number < 20){
      result += teen_name(number);
      number = 0;
    }
    else{
      // number is one of the tens (ex: Sixty)
      result += tens_name(number);
      number %= 10;
    }
  }
  
  // if number is 1 through 9, output the name (ex: One)
  if (number > 0){ 
    result += digit_name(number);
  }

  return result;
}

// main function - approved by Ms. B
int main() {
  int num;

  do{
    cout << "Please enter a number from 1 - 999: ";
    if (cin >> num){
      if ((num >= 1) && (num <= 999))
        break;
    }
    else{
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    cout << "Invalid input, try again!\n";
  }
  while (true);

  cout << define(num);
}
```

Alternatively, you could have each function calculate its own portion of the original `number` and output the appropriate word(s), if any. That way, `define()` can just call all of the functions unconditionally and only the relevant words will be returned, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

// defines 1 through 9 
string digit_name(int number){
  static const char* words[] = {
    "One ",
    "Two ",
    "Three ",
    "Four ",
    "Five ",
    "Six ",
    "Seven ",
    "Eight ",
    "Nine "
  };
  // if number has 1 through 9, output the name (ex: One)
  number %= 10;
  if (number){
    return words[number-1];
  }
  return "";
}

// defines 11 through 19
string teen_name(int number){
  static const char* words[] = {
    "Eleven ",
    "Twelve ",
    "Thirteen ",
    "Fourteen ",
    "Fifteen ",
    "Sixteen ",
    "Seventeen ",
    "Eighteen ",
    "Nineteen " 
  };
  // if number has 11 through 19, output name (ex: Seventeen)
  number %= 100;
  if (number > 10 && number < 20){
    return words[number-11];
  }
  return "":
}

// defines 10 through 90 (20, 30, 40 ... 90)
string tens_name (int number){
  static const char* words[] = {
    "Ten ",
    "Twenty ",
    "Thirty ",
    "Forty ",
    "Fifty ",
    "Sixty ",
    "Seventy ",
    "Eighty ",
    "Ninty "
  };
  // if number divides by 10 and is not a teen, then it is one of the tens (ex: Sixty)
  number %= 100;
  if (number && (number < 11 || number > 19)){
    return words[(number/10)-1];
  }
  return "";
}

// defines 100 through 900 (200, 300, 400 ... 900)
string hun_name (int number){
  // if number divides by 100, then it is one of the hundreds (ex: Two Hundred)
  if (number >= 100) {
    return digit_name(number / 100) + "Hundred ";
  }
  return "";
}  

string define (int number){
  // defines what it will output based on the input of the user
  return hun_name(number) + tens_name(number) + teen_name(number) + digit_name(number);
}

// main function - approved by Ms. B
int main() {
  int num;

  do{
    cout << "Please enter a number from 1 - 999: ";
    if (cin >> num){
      if ((num >= 1) && (num <= 999))
        break;
    }
    else{
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    cout << "Invalid input, try again!\n";
  }
  while (true);

  cout << define(num);
}
```

Comment: This code definitely works, but I have not learned this yet. We haven't used static in class, so I still have no idea what I am doing, but your explanation makes it much more easier to understand what I did wrong. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Using the arrays (which don't have to be static locals, they could be globals instead) just makes the functions more efficient. You can just as easily go back to using `if` statements instead. The point is to break up the user's `number` into its individual components and then output the appropriate words for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code. This is what I got now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string digit_name(int digit) {
 // defines 1 through 9 
  if (digit == 1){
    return "One "; 
  }
  if (digit == 2){
    return "Two "; 
  }
  if (digit == 3){
    return "Three "; 
  }
  if (digit == 4){
    return "Four "; 
  }
  if (digit == 5){
    return "Five "; 
  }
  if (digit == 6){
    return "Six "; 
  }
  if (digit == 7){
    return "Seven "; 
  }
  if (digit == 8){
    return "Eight "; 
  }
  if (digit == 9){
    return "Nine"; 
  }
  return "";
}

string teen_name(int number){
  // defines 10 through 19
  if (number == 10){
    return "Ten "; 
  }
  if (number == 11){
    return "Eleven "; 
  }
  if (number == 12){
    return "Twelve "; 
  }
  if (number == 13){
    return "Thirteen "; 
  }
  if (number == 14){
    return "Fourteen"; 
  }
  if (number == 15){
    return "Fifteen"; 
  }
  if (number == 16){
    return "Sixteen"; 
  }
  if (number == 17){
    return "Seventeen"; 
  }
  if (number == 18){
    return "Eighteen"; 
  }
  if (number == 19){
    return "Nineteen"; 
  }
  return "";
}

string tens_name (int number){
  // defines 20 through 90 (20, 30, 40 ... 90)
  if (number >= 90){
    return "Ninety "; 
  }
  if (number >= 80){
    return "Eighty "; 
  }
  if (number >= 70){
    return "Seventy "; 
  }
  if (number >= 60){
    return "Sixty "; 
  }
  if (number >= 50){
    return "Fifty "; 
  }
  if (number >= 40){
    return "Forty "; 
  }
  if (number >= 30){
    return "Thirty "; 
  }
  if (number >= 20){
    return "Twenty "; 
  }
  return "";
}

// defines 100 through 900 (200, 300, 400 ... 900)
string hun_name (int number){
  return digit_name(number / 100) + "Hundred ";
}  

string define (int number){
  // defines what it will output based on the input of the user
  string result;
 
  // if number divides by 100, then it is one of the hundreds (ex: Two Hundred)
  if (number >= 100){
    result += hun_name(number);
    number %= 100;
  }

  // if number divides by 10...
  if (number >= 10){
    // if number is 11 through 19, output name (ex: Seventeen)
    if (number > 10 && number < 20){
      result += teen_name(number);
      number = 0;
    }
    else{
      // number is one of the tens (ex: Sixty)
      result += tens_name(number);
      number %= 10;
    }
  }

  // if number is 1 through 9, output the name (ex: One)
  if (number > 0){ 
    result += digit_name(number);
  }

  return result;
}

// main function - approved by Ms. B
int main() {
  int num;
  cout << "Please enter a number: ";
  cin >> num;
  cout << define (num) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```